# How to make a simple mask like in Hitfilm?

Tags: masking

So, I want to use Blender for motipn graphics, and I previously used Hitfilm Express. One of the most frustrating things in Blender is creating a mask. But how does one do that like in Hitfilm? In Hitfilm, you literally just add a mask in the properties of something, and then thats it. How does one do that in Blender?

And I want to know how do I make the mask transparent without using a color key node (right now to make the mask transparent, on the mix node, I put the background to be green, then I use the color key mode to make it transparent)

Comment: You add a mask node in the node tree and then that's it.

Comment: But I cant set the mask to be alpha

Comment: @Mzidare i'll edit the question to be more specific

Comment: You can use Set Alpha node(In Converters) and as an Alpha input use the mask. You can also use Alpha Over node with Alpha 0 background input and your image "over" input, but that leaves sometimes ugly rim, so the first option is better in most of the cases.

Comment: @Mzidare maybe post it as an answer?

Comment: @Mzidare I also wanted to ask, lets say ive added a plane, and I have another plane, and I want to onoy mask put one plane, how do I do that?

Comment: Could you rephrase this question? I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but you can change object ID of one of the planes to 1 or something, turn on Object Index in Render Layers properties and use the ID to mask the plane.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Set Alpha node(In Converters) and as an Alpha input use the mask. You can also use Alpha Over node with Alpha 0 background input and your image "over" input, but that leaves sometimes ugly rim, so the first option is better in most of the cases.